# Find next password expiration date in Windows

Tags: windows-10, passwords, windows-domain

At work we just switched to having our normal logins be restricted and using a separate login with elevated privileges when necessary (such as for installing software, etc.).  We always login with our normal restricted accounts, then use `Run as different user...` when we need to elevate privileges.  The issue I'm having with this now is that the elevated password expires significantly sooner than my normal login, but because I don't login to the computer with the elevated account I never get a warning that it's about to expire.

I found a command that purports to show the next expiration date:

```
net user [username] /domain
```

This provides a list of outputs including the following:

```
The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain DOMAIN.Local.

User name                    [username]
Full Name                    [Full Name]
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never
Password last set            11/1/2017 6:30:15 AM
Password expires             1/30/2018 6:30:15 AM
Password changeable          11/2/2017 6:30:15 AM
```

You can see that it says the password expires in 90 days, however this morning it expired, despite still having more than a month until the date it said.

Why might this be reporting the wrong expiration date, and can it be corrected?

Is there a better or more accurate way to find an account's password expiration date?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

In similar environment to the one you describe and with similar requirement, I consistently get accurate expiry info on my logged in and other accounts from my x64 Win10 box.  

Thoughts:  
1. policy changed after NET USER inquiry
2. sync problems between domain controllers  
3. since fixed by Win10 (or perhaps server) update/s.

Would be keen to hear about (attempted) interventions, whether the problem reoccurred or was resolved etc.